# PreventTouchStream has null event (WebViewInputDispatcher)

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

In a cordova App context, the touch events are not dispatched/propagated in some specific cases to the parent element because the following exception:

`PreventTouchStream has null event (WebViewInputDispatcher)`

Unfortunately, googling the info did not provide any information.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution or explanation for this? I am getting same error.

Comment: Same here. Just now my Project manager informed me that the site I am trying to login is showing popup on login, and webview shows error as it prevents that. See if that's case in your url. Else no other clue. :(